# Android EditText in a dialog

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I have dialog with EditText in it.I want to get keyboad for the editbox automaticaly.i.e, when the dialog is displayed the keyboard should be shown. Is there any way to display the keyboard without touching on the EditText.

I have added the dialog code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(APP_NAME);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    // Use an EditText view to get user input.
    final EditText inputDevice = new EditText(this);
    final EditText inputTester = new EditText(this);

    if (id == DLG_ID_TESTER) {
        inputTester.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
        // inputTester.setThreshold(1);
        inputTester.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        inputTester.requestFocus();
        inputTester.setId(TXT_ID);
        builder.setView(inputTester);
    } else {
        inputDevice.setId(TXT_ID);
        inputDevice.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        builder.setView(inputDevice);
    }
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            if (id == DLG_ID_TESTER) {
                String val = inputTester.getText().toString();
                testerName = val;
                txtTesterName.setText(testerName);
            } else if (id == DLG_ID_DEVICE) {
                String value = inputDevice.getText().toString();
                deviceId = value;
                txtDeviceId.setText(deviceId);

            }
            return;
        }

    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;

                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**YOUR_VIEW**.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0); 
            }
        },200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the OnFocusChange() method to see when the whole dialog gets focus, and then call the getWindow().setSoftInputMode() with an "always visible" input mode.